# Can't log in to Dot Net Core 3 ASP.Net App with Chrome, but works with Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, asp.net-core, cookies, .net-core

I have the following code in my dot net core 3.1 web app with an angular frontend. The dot net core site is basically just a bunch of API controllers. All the frontend stuff is handled by an Angular 9 app.

```
public async Task<LogInResultDto> LogIn(LoginDto request)
{
    var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(request.UserName);
    if (user != null)
    {
        SignInResult result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user, request.Password, request.RememberMe, false);
        return result.ToDto();
    }

    return new LogInResultDto()
    {
        Success = false
    };
}
```

In firefox this works great, and I can query `User?.Identity?.IsAuthenticated` in my controller and it returns true if the user has logged in. In chrome this value is ALWAYS false. The login succeeds, but this value returns false.

In my startup I have the below code. Again this all works great in Firefox, but Chrome is stricter about something that I can't quite figure out.

Greatly appreciate any help.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   // ... some more things happen before this
    var urlPath = (Configuration.GetValue<string>("Common:BaseUrl") ?? string.Empty);
    var cookie_end = Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(urlPath)).Replace("=", "");

    services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(o => { })
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddCookie(options =>
            {
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                options.Cookie.Name = "TheCookie_" + cookie_end;
                options.Cookie.SameSite = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.SameSiteMode.Strict;
            });

    services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
        options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 5;
        options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = false;
    });

    services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
    {
        options.Cookie.Name = $"TheCookie_{cookie_end}.Auth";
    });

    services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Strict;
        options.HttpOnly = HttpOnlyPolicy.None;
        options.Secure = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
    });

    services.AddMvc(options =>
    {
        options.EnableEndpointRouting = false;
    }).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Latest);

   // ... some more stuff after
}
```

And then

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory, ILogger<Startup> logger)
{
    // a few things before here 
    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseCookiePolicy();

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        endpoints.MapBroadcastingEndpoints();
    });

     app.UseSpa(spa =>
    {
    });
    // some more things after here
}
```

**Update 1.** I think @Poke might be on to something with his comment regarding https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/upcoming-samesite-cookie-changes-in-asp-net-and-asp-net-core/ and Chrome changing something pertaining to how it uses cookies. I'm quite sure this worked in chrome before. But I cant seem to figure out what I am supposed to change to get it working again. I can see the .Auth Cookie is being set in Chrome, so it is at least partly working.

**Update 2.** Just to be clear. With both Chrome and Firefox, `_signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync();` returns a successfull result. In Firefox `User?.Identity?.IsAuthenticated == true` in all subsequent requests, and all `User.Claims` are set. In Chrome `IsAuthenticated` is false, and no claims are set.

**Update 3.** I can see that a cookie is being set in Chrome as well. Note that my cookie is not named "TheCookie", but the one I am seeing ends in `.Auth`. I only see this one cookie, same in Firefox.

From Chome:
[image]
From Firefox: 
[image]

Comment: My guess without further details: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/upcoming-samesite-cookie-changes-in-asp-net-and-asp-net-core/

Comment: @poke setting SamSite.None, or Unspecified made no difference, Firefox works, Chrome does not.

Comment: @poke but I do think you are on to something, I'm quite sure Chrome worked before, and just recently stopped. Maybe because of that update.

Comment: Do the chrome dev tools say anything? Also check if the cookies are actually set. Just compare the requests in Firefox’ and Chrome’s network tool.

Comment: @poke I figured out what my issue was, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This was originally filed as a bug by a user, and I could not reproduce in test or production environment, but I could reproduce it in my local dev environment, and now I know why.

Its all about the HTTPS.

In my local dev environment I did not have HTTPS redirecting enabled. So when the project built and started in firefox it went to a HTTPS page, when I then started Chrome and typed in the address I was visiting the site with HTTP. Chrome does not include cookies in HTTP sites, even if they are flagged as not secure (I tried disabling the secure property with no success).

I can't take all the credit for this though, had a person helping me test and they realized it only occurred in prod when they went in using the HTTP url and it worked everywhere when using HTTPS.

Now redirect to HTTPs is enabled everywhere, and everyone is happy.